# add items on top of the listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and I am using list.add(mylist) and adapter.notifydatasetchanged() ,its adding the items below the existing list ,How Do I add the Items on Top of the List.

Eg: If I receive new msgs It should be on top of the existing list.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `add(int index, E object)`. Where `index = 0`.

Comment: Thanks techiservices.It works,I have another query the list adds data in ascending order in other words the first Item goes to the bottom of the list and the last item from the query received goes to the top ,Is there any way I can Reverse the sequence like DESC in list Descending.Thanks agin for the right answer.+1

Comment: @Jason Wood.  Was just doing an edit to say you may be better sorting the list, maybe on a Date/Time, depending on what fields you have of course, and offering the option of how to sort to the user.

Comment: Yes I will try to get the query in ORDER BY DESC right ? I guess that should work.Thanks again.Have a great day.

Comment: If your data comes from a database, then yes, `ORDER BY DESC` is a nice easy way to sort your data. Thanks for the accept ;) and a good day to you.

Comment: @techServices Another Query How do I scroll to top of the list when I add data to the list?

Comment: Have a look at `ListView.setSelection(int position)` or `ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`.  The latter only available to API 8 and later.

Comment: I'm not sure if `setSelection` will do what you want.  I've never tried it, so let me know if it works.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you bind your adapter to your ListView, you can also just insert the item into your adapter with the position (in this case 0)

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

...

```
adapter.insert(data, 0);
```

It shoudl update by itself because you had it bound